# How to Programmatic-ally Change the Mode of an Open File?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please tell me whether it is possible to programmatic-ally change the mode of a file?

I have opened a file for reading as follows:

```
op = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
fileOpened = open(op, 'rt')
```

I need more, without closing it, change the mode to 'wt'

Comment: You can't change the open mode of a file. If you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you achieve it in some other way.

Comment: Try : import fcntl, os ; fcntl.fcntl(op, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_WRONLY)

Comment: @ArunMu ["F_SETFL: Set the file status flags to the value specified by arg.  File access mode (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR) and file creation flags (i.e., O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC) in arg are ignored."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) This probably won't work on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I had read this, but was not quite sure what exactly it meant. That's why said to "try" :)

Comment: A better description from GNU: "The file access modes allow a file descriptor to be used for reading, writing, or both. (On GNU/Hurd systems, they can also allow none of these, and allow execution of the file as a program.) The access modes are chosen when the file is opened, and never change."